# Bootstrap: collapsed text conflicts with footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I have this [page](http://arcane-gorge-6631.herokuapp.com/debate/1), built upon Bootstrap, and the thing is that if you click the "See Wikipedia" button, the content will flush the whole page, however the page height does not change and the footer is overwritten in a very funny ugly way. Is it possible to change this? I have tried to set some overflow but it does not help much.

Comment: I have seen this before it usually ends up being you have an open <div> somewhere in the page. most likely near the end of the collapse code.

Comment: @Zeeba I actually did that, but it does not work for me

Comment: try puting your footer in a row <div class="row"><footer class="site-footer"></footer></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this small changes :

Change

```
<div id="debate-title" class="container">
```

By

```
<div id="debate-title" class="container  col-xs-6 ">
```

Change

```
<footer class="site-footer">
```

By

```
<footer class="site-footer col-xs-12">
```

Comment: Wow nice it worked!, thanks a lot, what kind of magic is this?

Comment: he used bootstrap layout classes

Comment: It is very nice, I do not need to use an empty div with fixed length now, it is better than that ugly hack

Comment: My mentor are still saying me RTFM, I hate him when I heard this ^^ You should read the doc too : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @dorafmon Hi Mr, you didn't finish your sentence, and now you ?? As your website is in Italy, and you in GB; I think you'll have news from me tomorrow morning ^^ [ i'll delete this comment tomorrow ]. buonanotte

Comment: @Jahnux73 Sorry I thought I canceled adding comment but clearly I post it without knowing posting it. My apologies. I was going to ask how to create a gab between two col-xs-6s but I got a work-around myself :)